# PHP/MySQL Statements. How do I turn this into a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO user_answer (facebook_id, answer_id) VALUES (' . $i . ',' . $randAnswer . ')';
$dbh->exec($query);
```

I have this code, and now am required to turn it into a prepared statement using PDO::bindValue() and maybe PDO::prepare(). Looking at the examples, I'm not sure how to go about this. Where does the :name come from and why are you putting it in the bindValue part?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I kind of wanted an "explain like I'm five" for it, not a link.

Comment: :name is ur own variable name. eg: u can use :name in ur sql query and then in bindValue(':name', $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: I come here because I'm confused about something, I want clarification and to ask a question and it gets closed? You guys are so helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it would look something like this:

```
$st = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user_answer (facebook_id, answer_id) VALUES (:facebook_id, :answer_id)");

$st->execute(array('facebook_id' => $i, 'answer_id' => $randAnswer));
```

You might want to read [a tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or two to get an idea how to use PDO effectively. The [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) is also pretty good.

The general idea here is to put in things like `:name` where the name value goes, and then pass in an array that defines what `name` maps to.

Comment: Why do I have to execute it as an array?

Comment: That's how you do the binding. Regular `?` style placeholders still require an array, but don't need labels.

Answer (score 0):

it looks way better without useless labels

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO user_answer (facebook_id, answer_id) VALUES (?,?)';
$stmt  = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($i,$randAnswer));
```

At least your query fits into screen.